# JavaScript: how can i use a function in a constructor

Tags: javascript

the following code doesnt work:

```
function CClass() {
   myFunc(); //says it doesnt know about myFunc
}

CClass.prototype = {
   myFunc: function () {}
};
```

thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you expect this snippet to do. Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function CClass() {
   this.myFunc();    
}
```

and see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/N9wem/

Answer (score 1):

`myFunc` is not in global scope.

You should use

```
function CClass() {
   this.myFunc(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CClass.prototype.myFunc = function(){
    alert("myFunc")
};

function CClass() {
   this.myFunc();
}

c = new CClass()
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
function CClass() {
   this.myFunc()
}

CClass.prototype = {
   myFunc: function () { 
      alert('hello from prototype');
  }
};


var cc = new CClass();   // hello from prototype
```